# Дано: пользователь вводит строку, если в строке есть слово "Hello" вывести "Hi", если есть слово "Love" вывести "Love you too"

Tags: java, циклы, if, switch

А если есть оба слова то вывести "Hi" "Love you too" "Hi, love you too".
Выглядит примерно так:

Строка: "Hello, nice weather"
Вывод программы: "Hi"

Строка: "I Love you"
Вывод программы: "Love you too"

Строка: "Hello, I Love you"
Вывод программы:
"Hi"
"Love you too"
"Hi, Love you too"

Это все надо сделать с помощью if-else или цикла. У меня возникла проблема в последнем случае, так как если в введенном предложении совпадают оба слова, то надо вывести обе предыдущие фразы + ещё одну новую, и того в выводе в последнем случае должно вывести 3 фразы.
Пример моего кода:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String phrase = input.nextLine();
    if (phrase.equals("Hello")) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    } else if (phrase.equals("Love")) {
        System.out.println("Love you too");
    } else if ((phrase.equals("Hello")) && (phrase.equals("Love"))) {
        System.out.println("Hi, Love you too");
    }
```

Справиться с проблемой, помогло удаление else, спасибо!

Comment: Конкретную "проблему" мы должны угадать, или Вам просто весь код написать? И что-то я не вижу в примерах ввода слова "Hello".

Comment: @Igor я не понимаю как в последнем варианте сделать так, чтобы выводились все варианты совпадений а не только один из них.

Comment: Покажите свой код.

Comment: Если вам нужно отдельное слово, то зачем вы сравниваете всю строку? Ясное дело, что одна и та же строка не может одновременно равняться "Hello" и "Love".

Comment: @Vladislava Ruzyak Убери else и вместо equals напиши contains, затем print, вместо println.

Comment: В последнем случае непонятно какой вывод должен быть.

Comment: @Roman C Строка: "Hello, I Love you" Вывод программы: "Hi" "Love you too" "Hi, Love you too"

Comment: Так нужно три строки вывести или одну?

Comment: Как это понимать "Это все надо сделать с помощью if-else или цикла"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте contains() для проверки вхождения слова в строку.
Для того, чтобы условия не исключали друг друга и программа работала согласно Вашим ожиданиям, вместо "else if" стоит использовать просто "if".

Для игнорирования регистра можно изначально привести входную строку к нижнему регистру методом toLoverCase() и производить поиск именно в нижнем регистре.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String phrase = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

if(phrase.contains("hello")){
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
if(phrase.contains("love")){
    System.out.println("Love you too");
}
if(phrase.contains("hello") && phrase.contains("love")){
    System.out.println("Hi, Love you too");
}
```

Comment: Зачем игнорить регистр? Этого нет в задании.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh, полностью согласен, немного лишнего написал.

Comment: Ответ неверный, требуется использовать `if-else`

Comment: @RomanC, поясните, почему? Насколько я вижу, в условиях есть только "если" и никаких "иначе". А использовать можно условные операторы или циклы, я использовал именно условный оператор.

Comment: "Это все надо сделать с помощью if-else". Вот это условие. А вы его нарушили, т.к. использовали только if. В этот то и вся суть...

Comment: @RomanC, ну очевидно же, в условии задачи имеется ввиду именно условный оператор. Тем более, автор подтвердил, что именно использование "else" мешало ему решить задачу.

Comment: @rhino_rus Если бы требовался только условный оператор `if`, то я бы не писал тут комменты, но ОП сказала что требуется `if-else`, а это коренным образом меняет задачу. Тем более что ошибка была связана именно с `if-else`. ОП не меняла условие, то что она поставила галочку на ответе не означает, что он верный.

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. проверять нужно не на равенство, а не вхождение, то и использовать нужно не `.equals()`, а `.contains()`.

Comment: И куда-то case insensitive присобачить.

Comment: И else выкинуть.